# Unable to set a custom class for UITableViewController in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder

Xcode will not let me set the custom class of my table view to the following class(when I go to set it on the storyboard it does not let me and nothing comes up on the drop down).

> The following is my swift file for my table view controller.

https://gist.github.com/JudeMolloy/139e91d8c45ebe3d6140139ffd68a339

Here is a picture of my storyboard:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Did you created it using the Xcode Wizard?

Comment: What do you mean the Xcode Wizard? I created the file by right clicking then pressing new file and then a clicked on cocoa touch class and created the file

Comment: Yep, and in subclass did you choose UITableViewController?

Comment: No, I selected UITableViewController

Comment: Yes, typo mistake. So if you have in your class all the mandatory methods of the UITableViewDataSource Protocol class... I don't guess why you couldn't choose your controller...

Comment: I've answer with the very basic custom stub for a UITableViewCotroller. If that doesn't answer your question post, also your XCode Version, maybe a screen of XCode with your storyboard and maybe more code of your class.

Comment: That did not work, I will add the extra information just now.

Comment: So you have selected the UITableView and not the UITableViewController. Select this last one (either with the yellow icon on the above bar or from the controller list section on the left, not shown in your image) and that we’ll do the trick.

Comment: I did that but now I get the following error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "KonectionsTableVC" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'

Comment: Start over, choose from class picker from the bottom right corner a UITableViewController an put it in your storyboard, than assign your controller. Did you get the same error?

Comment: Try also to start with fix values without calling fetchUsers

Comment: I did not do the fix values thing but the controller seems to work now, however, the table view doesn't display any of the data? Is there something wrong with my controller file?

Comment: If your fetchUser is asynchronous and It should as you use firebase, you need to call table.reloadData once you have a full array of user.

Comment: I added self.tableView.reloadData() after my fetchUsers() in the viewDidLoad function but nothing has changed. Am I doing this the correct way?

Comment: You already have my answer, it's the one with pictures. Do you want that I change it with the reloadData stuff? But I think that goes out of topic, 'cause the question was for the Controller Drop Down Box. Anyway happy you had your work done! :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check If your class has at least these methods:

```
//
//  MyCustomTableViewController.swift
//  Test Table
//
//  Created by shadowsheep on 17/02/2018.
//  Copyright © 2018 shadowsheep. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class MyCustomTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 0
    }

}
```

With these basic stub you shold be able to access your controller for a UITableViewController for sure...

**Edit**
From the new info provided:
You must select the UITableView**Controller** and not the UiTableView. Once selected your UITableView**Controller** yoy will be able to set your custom controller.

[image]

You'll see you have selected the right class because the light grey default class provided on the Identity Inspector is **UITableViewController**

Than you can find your custom controller in the dropdown menu.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the picture you provided, you have selected the UITableView, not the view controller.

You cannot set the custom class of a UITableView to a view controller.

Make sure you select the view controller in the storyboard. Click the yellow icon in the bar above your view controller. Then you will be able to set the custom class.

Comment: I did that but then I get the following error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "KonectionsTableVC" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'

Comment: In your Swift file, KonectionsTableVC doesn’t declare a tableView. Open the storyboard and control-drag from your table view to just inside your KonectionsTableVC class. When prompted, create an Outlet named tableView. That should resolve the exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a custom class on a controller, the custom class you want to choose should have inheritance of that controller, in this case, `UITableViewController`.

Let's say you want to use `ViewController` as a controller custom class, set its parent to `UITableViewController`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

Then you can see `ViewController` in the custom class dropdown at inspector tab:

[image: select custom class]